# Islamic political questions repeatedly closed down despite no consensus and valid rationale

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons, on-topic-definition

[A second question regarding Al-Quds day](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16139/is-it-obligatory-for-muslims-to-participate-in-al-quds-day-rally), (and the latest in a long list of questions on politics of Islam) was closed down unilaterally by a mod, despite the fact there's neither any consensus by the community nor any valid reason as to off-topic-ness of such questions.

So can the mod explain why questions on Islamic politics are routinely closed down for being off-topic or irrelevant to study of Islam? [Here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1236/why-was-the-question-about-al-quds-day-closed) and on many other occasions I have already explained why questions of Islamic politics are part of Islamic history and jurisprudence and therefore on topic. But the mod continues to close them down on sight without the consent of the community or any valid reason.

Answer (score 2):

He doesn't have to say anything, you just didn't read what the close reason says:

> Questions on politics are off-topic as they're rarely productive or relevant to the teachings of Islam." – goldPseudo

This is not a politics site, this is an islamic site. This is not the moderator's fault you should visit the help center to learn what questions are ontopic.

Whether you agree or not, this site doesn't accept such questions because they can't fit the stackexchange format of Q&A, you might want to try a discussion site instead.

Comment: The close reason you quoted, is a default close option of the parent StackExchange, but it can be altered according to specific features of each site. That policy can not justify closing a question on *Islamic politics*. It just doesn't apply to questions that are on-topic according to the general subject of the site. If we want to take that as an absolute overarching rule, then politics.SE must be entirely closed down for being an off-topic *site*!

Comment: The point is: such questions can bring up lengthy discussions which is not what we want here. You can ask in chat.

Comment: It is a scholarly question of Islamic jurisprudence! Lengthy discussions can emerge from any other topics. They should be prevented on notice not on prediction!

Comment: I'm not going to get into a debate with you, this has already been discussed and answered here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/985/islamic-politics-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

In the opinion of many of the educated people, and especially many of the religious scholars, Islam has nothing to do with politics. They believe Islam and politics to be issues separate from one another. This is what the governments would like us to think; this is the idea that the foreigners have instilled into us from the beginning. Many promote the notion that the clerks should have nothing to do with political matters. When wanting to defame a clerk they would say:" This is a political clerk!" They say that Islam is separate from politics; that religion is separate from politics, but these people haven't understood Islam. The government of Islam was formed at the time of the Prophet. what is politics? Politics is the formation of policies dealing with the relationship between a ruler or government and the people or other governments, and with the prevention of corruption in society. In Islam, all these policies exist. In fact, Islam has more rules pertaining to politics than it does to worship. The books relating to the political aspects of Islam by far outnumber those concerned with worship. This mistaken notion has been put into our minds so that now some of the gentlemen, the clergymen believe that Islam has nothing to do with politics, that it consists of a few ordinances concerning worship which is itself a personal matter between God and man. You can go to your mosques and pray and recite the Qur'an as much as you’d like, and the governments will leave you alone. But this is not Islam. Islam stands up to the oppressor, it orders the people to do battle with the Taghout (oppressor) and with those who rebel against God. So with all these rules for battle, for jihad and so on, is Islam so far removed from politics?! Does Islam mean nothing other than going to the mosques, praying and reciting the Qur'an?! Islam is not only this. Islam has political laws which must be implemented.