# Would "Islam Stack Exchange is an online Islam study group" or a variant thereof be a suitable scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

As a compromise solution to the kind of stalemate we have here [Let's go back to the old scope description?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/17163), I want to toss around this idea:

**Question**: Would "*Islam Stack Exchange is an online Islam study group*" or a variant thereof be a suitable scope?

This refers to the first line on the [on-topic](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, which is used in numerous other places on StackExchange.  I just want to gauge community opinion on this; I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

(I'm also not sure if it's possible to change it to something other than "Islam Stack Exchange is for ...".)

How I feel about it:

- *Pro*: The word "study" gives the sense of being "academic" (i.e., we're here to study, not here to help you with your masturbation problems) without it sounding overly elitist and exclusive.
- *Pro*: The word "study" indicates effort is required.
- *Pro*: It rephrases the "who's it for" (an objection to the original scope) and replaces it with "what it is", which is similar to the style at [Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("Skeptics Stack Exchange is for challenging unreferenced notable claims, pseudoscience and biased results.").
- *Con*: It's a bit of a mismatch with the "question and answer" style of the site.

---

This is how it would look in conjunction with the first paragraph I proposed here [Proposed revision of the FAQ (on-topic) page, February 2017](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1858/17163):

> **Islam Stack Exchange** is an online Islam study group.
>
> Anyone may participate constructively here, regardless of their beliefs. We welcome useful contributions from the viewpoints of all denominations, provided they are not ascribed as belonging to groups that do not hold those viewpoints. For the purposes of this site, Islam includes all groups that identify themselves as Islamic.
>
> ...

Comment: Islam.SE doesnt help you with your masturbation problems lol 